# How do I clear $error and $LASTEXITCODE set by an external cmdlet or executable?

Tags: powershell

I have a custom module wrapping an external command (`csrun.exe`), and parses the output so I can use it in PowerShell.

Everything just about works except if the external command writes to `stderror`, and clearing the error in my cmdlet doesn't seem to fully work. It will clear (i.e. `$error.count` is `0` and `$lasterrorcode` is `0`, but once I return to the script that is calling my cmdlet, `$error` and `$lasterrorcode` are no longer clear and the error in `$error` references the underlying exception for the external command

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The compute emulator is not running.
```

I've attempted, try-catches, clearing the mentioned variables. Regardless, the calling script retains a reference to the error.

### CustomModule.psm1

```ps
$__azureEmulatorPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Emulator\"SDKs\Azure\Emulator\"
$__azureEmulator = __azureEmulatorPath + "csrun.exe"

function Get-EmulatorStatus() {
    [OutputType([ComputeEmulatorStatus])] 
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param()

    $output = (& $__azureEmulator /status | Out-String)

    if ($error.Count -gt 0 -or $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        Write-Host ($Error | Format-List -Force | Out-String)
        Write-Host Clearing Error and Continuing
        $error.Clear()
        $LASTEXITCODE = 0
    }

    #error from command cleared here

    return $output
}

export-modulemember -function *
```

### Test.ps1

```
import-module "CustomModule.psm1" # definew cmdlet Get-EmulatorStatus

$status = Get-EmulatorStatus

# even though error cleared in cmdlet, still here
Write-Host Write-Host Error $LASTEXITCODE, $Error.Count
Write-Host ($Error | Format-List -Force | Out-String)
```

Comment: Does your cmdlet have a `[CmdletBinding]`? If so, it should support `-ErrorAction Ignore`, which will not fill the `$Error` variable.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code and also could you please let us know that what  it is doing in a nutshell

Comment: Added test code, though I did simplify for presentation. the `ErrorAction` isn't ideal because I only want to ignore the underlying call to the command because I _know_ its an error I want to ignore. If anything else comes up I want the error to bubble up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using one of two options:

- use *exit* from your cmdlet, e.g. *exit 0* (preferred).
- use a global scope when setting the codes explicitly,  E.g.
  *$global:LASTEXITCODE*

I ran into this calling robocopy that sets non-zero exit codes even on success, and interfered with Jenkin's automation.

Comment: While I haven't had a chance to verify, I'm pretty sure a global scope will work. The exit on cmdlet doesn't work though. I think the errors are applied to the global stack. If you happen to know a good blog or some documentation on handling errors when using the call-operator, I would appreciate it, but the global does work. Thanks!

Comment: You're right that I wouldn't expect the errors to be affected by the exit, but as far as something like a batch file checking for an exit code it should work.  Good luck.

Comment: @AndyNorborg, I can't comment yet on your original question (still under 50 rep) - but would recommend making it more searchable for the future by changing the title to something like: "How do I clear $errors and $LASTEXITCODE set by an external cmdlet or executable?"